# bash / sh script to replace text between some tags/strings in a text file

Tags: shell, replace, openwrt

I am creating executable which will be executed with /bin/sh or /bin/bash script,
I have a file which contains a structure like, there will be only one `#start` and `#end` tag in the config file, and I want to replace text in between those tags,

```
...

#start
FirewallRuleSet global {
    FirewallRule allow tcp to google.com
    FirewallRule allow tcp to facebook.com

#more rules
}
#end

FirewallRuleSet known-users {
    FirewallRule allow to 0.0.0.0/0
}

...
```

Desired output will be,

```
...

#start
FirewallRuleSet global {
    FirewallRule allow tcp to google.com
    FirewallRule deny tcp to facebook.com
    FirewallRule deny tcp to twitter.com
    FirewallRule allow tcp to exaple.com



#more rules
}
#end

FirewallRuleSet known-users {
    FirewallRule allow to 0.0.0.0/0
}

...
```

How can I replace the whole text between `#start` and `#end` with some new text? I just want to add or remove Rules from this config file.

This is part of a config file and I want to modify url allowed inside that texts.

Comment: @don_crissti there are no multiple tags, added exampe output.

Comment: OK. I've edited Lucas' answer as it was very close to what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
sed '/#start/,/#end/replace_command'
```

For example, if the file is called `myconfig`,
and you want to replace "allow" with "deny" in that section, you could say

```
sed '/#start/,/#end/s/allow/deny/' myconfig
```

That would leave the file untouched, and display on the standard output
what the file would look like after the modification. 
You should probably do that first,
to verify that you've got the command right. 
If you want to actually change the file, add the **`-i`** option:

```
sed -i '/#start/,/#end/s/allow/deny/' myconfig
```

If you want to replace the *whole* text (*all* the text)
between those two lines,
you can do something slightly simpler than [Lucas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/272078/80216):

```
sed '/#start/,/#end/c\
New text line 1\
New text line 2\
        ︙      \
New text line n-1\
New text line n (last)'                                   ← Close quote; no backslash here
```

**`c`** is the **c**hange command in `sed` (and `ed`);
it means "replace entire line(s)". 
You cannot simply leave the `#start` and `#end` lines untouched. 
If you want to keep them, you must re-insert them:

```
sed -i '/#start/,/#end/c\
#start\
FirewallRuleSet global {\
    FirewallRule allow tcp to google.com\
    FirewallRule deny tcp to facebook.com\
                      ︙                 \
\
#more rules\
}\
#end' myconfig
```

`/#start/,/#end/` specifies a range —
the lines from the first line that contains `#start`
through the first line after that that contains `#end`. 
If you need to find lines that contain those strings and nothing else,
use `/^#start$/,/^#end$/`.

Comment: Thanks @G-man. I tried this once before,  but I want to replace whole text between those #start and #end

Comment: doesnt work for me

Comment: @NadavB: Well, it has worked for a few people, and I don’t see any other complaints.  “doesn’t work” is very broad.  If you would say more about your situation (what you want to do, with what input), what you tried and what actually happened, I might be able to give you some help. But we discourage such conversations in comments; so they are limited to 600 characters.  You should probably [ask a new question](/questions/ask) (with the information I asked for, and a link back to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/272061/80216)) and then post another comment here to alert me to it.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [G-Man's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/272062/88313) and the comment:

```
sed -i '/#start/,/#end/ {
//!d
/#start/a\
some new text\
more lines\
end of new text (no backslash here!)
}' myconfig
```

Explanation:

1. `/#start/,/#end/ { .... }` executes the commands in curly brackets for every line between the text "#start" and "#end" (inclusive). Compare G-Man's answer.
2. `a` is the append command.  It is only executed on the line matching "#start" in order to add the new text. It appends the lines until a line that is not terminated with a backslash+newline.

Comment: This answer could be improved if you would [edit] it to explain how it works in comparison to mine — specifically, (1) the function of the  `{`…`}`, (2) the function of the  `//!d`, and (3) why it explicitly references the `/#start/` pattern twice.

Comment: @don_chrissti: how does the `//!d` part in your edit work? I am wondering why it does not delete the "#start" and "#end" lines. So my question is: What does `//` match? The empty string or some previous regex (which)?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have two states that the presence of two different lines shift between this is a job for awk (or perl or python).  Since my current language is python the program would look like this:

```
import sys

rule_file = sys.argv[1]
new_rules = sys.argv[2]

mode = "save_rules"
for line in open(rule_file):
    line = line.strip()
    if line == "#start":
        print line
        print new_rules
        mode = "replace_rules"
    elif line == "#end":
        mode = "save_rules"
        print line
    elif mode == "save_rules":
        print line
```

Now save this into rule_replace.py and call it with

```
python rule_replace.py my_rule_file.txt 'FirewallRuleSet global {
FirewallRule allow tcp to google.com
FirewallRule deny tcp to facebook.com
FirewallRule deny tcp to twitter.com
FirewallRule allow tcp to exaple.com



#more rules
}' >new_rules.txt
```

Of course you do not have to put the new rules on the command line, I am assuming you would have them in a shell variable and then the call would look like:

```
$ python rule_replace.py my_rule_file.txt $new_rules
```

Note that this script, while it works, is not a solution for something in production.  It does not catch any errors (for instance if the source file is not there).  It assumes without checking that a #start line is always followed by an #end line and that the lines are exactly as you described. It also could use some logging if going into production.

Answer (score 0):

Building off G-Man's answer, here's how to do this AND use custom delimiters AND variable substitution (due to the complexity this wasn't immediately obvious)

Given inputfile.txt:

```
Line1
Line2
<!-- /START_MARKER/ -->
Line4
Line5
Line6
<!-- /END_MARKER/ -->
Line8
Line9
```

Use these commands/script:

```
customtext="Any kind of variable text here"

sed -i '\%<!-- /START_MARKER/ -->%,\%<!-- /END_MARKER/ -->%c\
foo '"$customtext"' abcxyz whatever' inputfile.txt
```

Results in:

```
Line1
Line2
Any kind of variable text here
Line8
Line9
```

There's a lot going on here, explained below:

`'` - Using single quotes must be done to wrap everything

`\%` - When using a custom delimiter (e.g. if your marker has `/` you MUST use a different delimiter) it has to be escaped here

`<!-- /START_MARKER/ -->` - the literal start marker, in this case it's a whacky example for demonstration purposes.

`%` - sed delimiter, not escaped

`,` - comma (?)

`\%` - sed delimiter again, this time MUST be escaped

`<!-- /END_MARKER/ -->` - Literal ending marker

`%c` - sed delimiter (not escaped) and `c`

`\` - backslash, signifying the following text/lines should be used as the replacement

`foo` - some replacement text

`'"$customtext"'` - custom variable text, note the use of `'` and then `"` to enable variable replacement, then `"` and `'` to return to free text mode

`abcxyz whatever` - some additional replacement text

`'` - closing single quote

`inputfile.txt` - the file name